# How do I configure Dask distributed logging levels with an environment variable?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

It feels like I should be able to read between the lines of https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/debug.html and https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html to craft an environment variable name and value, but none of

```
DASK_DISTRIBUTED__LOGGING=DEBUG
DASK_LOGGING_DISTRIBUTED=DEBUG
DASK__LOGGING__DISTRIBUTED=DEBUG
DASK__LOGGING__DISTRIBUTED__SCHEDULER=DEBUG
```

nor the equivalents with `10` instead of `DEBUG`, nor some other combinations of order and underscore seem to do the trick.

Comment: The first environment variable, `export DASK_DISTRIBUTED__LOGGING=DEBUG` is the correct syntax. If you use [`dask.config.get`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/configuration.html#dask.config.get) do you see the correct variable? Could you provide more information on where the environment variables are set and how you're deploying Dask?

Comment: I was setting them in Docker containers running the scheduler and workers. I'm away at the moment but will get the config when I get back, thanks